# foreach loop in database table column with multiple images

Tags: php, heidisql

```
<?php  
    $images= $uploading['front_image'];
    $whileimg= explode(",", $images);
    foreach ($whileimg as $key => $image) {
        echo  $uploading["front_image"];          
    }
?>
```

In database I have my images saved in one column(2,3,4 it depends). now when I want them all to show in web ,Instead of images I get the path of the photos, as are saved in database. thank you

Comment: Hey @newuser - I have edited your question to improve the formatting of the code and to make it more readable

Comment: You need to make it an image take and echo the path in the img tag

Comment: I tried but didn't worked

Comment: There is another way to do it, just create a new table and join it. But @clearshot66 have the answer for your case

Answer (score 1):

To display images, you have use img tag

```
foreach ($whileimg as $key => $image) {
        echo  "<img src='".$image."' alt='image'>";   
    }
```

Comment: $whileimg might have only one element. Print it and see elements in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it an image take and echo the path in the img is what it sounds like you're getting:

```
 echo "<img src='".$image."' />
```

instead of

```
echo  $uploading["front_image"];
```

So:

```
<?php  
    $images= $uploading['front_image'];
    $whileimg= explode(",", $images);
    foreach ($whileimg as $key => $image) {
        echo "<img src='".$image."' />          
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well check your array of images because foreach don't terminate until a `break` is issued or the array ends

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are fetching comma separated paths of images using the following line:

```
$images= $uploading['front_image'];
```

You just need to use the following loop after creating array of paths:

```
foreach ($whileimg as $key => $image) {
    echo "<img src='$image'>";
}
```